# FTP Session isn't ending

Tags: bash, ftp

This is an urgent problem

So here's my problem  :

I am using this script on the crontab of a few computers and the FTP sessions doesn't ends so after a few, the FTP servers blocks everythings and the computer crashes

Here is the configuration of the FTP server, hosted on a NAS from QNAP TS-451+.

FTP is active:

[image: FTP is active]

Max FTP connections set to 512:

[image: Max ftp connections set to 512]

Here the code for the FTP session :

```
filename=foo.txt
hostname=myserver.net
remoteport=10021
path=/Web/PiTops_State/screen
localpath=~/
username=admin
password=*****
ftp -inv -p <<FTPSEND
open ${hostname} ${remoteport}
user ${username} ${password}
cd ${path}
binary
lcd ${localpath}
put ${filename}
bye
FTPSEND
```

The problem is that the FTP session doesn't seem to end so I have to restart the FTP server every day
The computers are rasperi pi 3 running PitopOS.

Update : Adding

```
close
bye
```

at the end doesnt works

Comment: set idle timeout for connections in ftp daemon.

Comment: Where is that in the QNAP interface ?

Comment: try closing then exiting ftp . close ; bye

Comment: Like so ?

put [...]
close
bye

Comment: As I edited, adding close and bye doesnt solve it

Comment: Does the ftp connection close on the server if you start the ftp client by hand and supply those commands manually (rather than via redirection)? You might be better using `curl -T` to transfer the file which is more suited to batch use - though it depends if the issue is at client or server end.

Comment: @PaulHaldane the cURL -T option sounds really good though how does it works with ftp ? how do I pass arguments like user and passwd ? can I specify a path ?

Comment: @PaulHaldane And if the foo.txt file exists on the server, will it be overwritten ?

Comment: Something like `curl -T ${localpath}/${filename} -u ${username}:${password} ftp://${hostname}:${remoteport}/${path}/${filename}` should transfer file with destination using same name.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked like this for me : `curl -T FILENAME ftp://USER:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/path/`

Comment: actually @PaulHaldane, It does work like file upload works but after a little the FTP server still stops to function because max connection reached